# Use of undeclared identifier happening to specific function

Tags: c, function, cs50

I have the following error code popping up:

> ```
> In file included from filter.c:5:
> ./helpers.h:16:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'height'
> void swap(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pix, int width);
>                           ^
> ./helpers.h:16:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
> void swap(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pix, int width);
>                                   ^
> ./helpers.h:21:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'height'
> RGBTRIPLE value(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y);
>                                 ^
> ./helpers.h:21:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
> RGBTRIPLE value(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y);
>                                         ^
> 4 errors generated.
> In file included from helpers.c:1:
> ./helpers.h:16:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'height'
> void swap(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pix, int width);
>                           ^
> ./helpers.h:16:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
> void swap(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pix, int width);
>                                   ^
> ./helpers.h:21:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'height'
> RGBTRIPLE value(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y);
>                                 ^
> ./helpers.h:21:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
> RGBTRIPLE value(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y);
>                                         ^
> helpers.c:59:27: error: use of undeclared identifier 'height'
> void swap(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pix, int width){
>                           ^
> helpers.c:59:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
> void swap(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pix, int width){
>                                   ^
> helpers.c:78:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'height'
> RGBTRIPLE value(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y){
>                                 ^
> helpers.c:78:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
> RGBTRIPLE value(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y){
>                                         ^
> 8 errors generated.
> Makefile:2: recipe for target 'filter' failed
> make: *** [filter] Error 1
> ```

I really do not understand why is it that the function that I made have the `undeclared indentifier` error while the premade function (every other function other than `swap` and `value`) don't have this issue. I checked for spelling mistake and looking up on google of what `use of undeclared identifier` meant. But there no help as the error only happened to the ones that I made.

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]){
    int average = 0;
    RGBTRIPLE dot;

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            dot = image[i][j];
            average = round((dot.rgbtRed + dot.rgbtGreen + dot.rgbtBlue) / 3);
        }
    }
    return;
}

int max(int value){
    if(value > 255){
        return 255;
    }
    else{
        return value;
    }
}

// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]){
    RGBTRIPLE dot;

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            dot = image[i][j];
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = max(round(.393 * dot.rgbtRed + .769 * dot.rgbtGreen + .189 * dot.rgbtBlue));
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = max(round(.349 * dot.rgbtRed + .686 * dot.rgbtGreen + .168 * dot.rgbtBlue));
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = max(round(.272 * dot.rgbtRed + .534 * dot.rgbtGreen + .131 * dot.rgbtBlue));
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]){
    int n;

    if(width % 2 != 0){
        n = 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0, k = (width - n) / 2; j < k; j++){
            swap(image, i, j, width);
        }
    }
    return;
}

void swap(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pix, int width){
    RGBTRIPLE temp;

    temp = image[row][pix];
    image[row][pix] = image[row][width - pix];
    image[row][width - pix] = temp;
}

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]){

    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++){
            image[i][j] = value(image, i, j)
        }
    }
    return;
}

RGBTRIPLE value(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y){
    int count = 0;
    int red;
    int blue;
    int green;
    RGBTRIPLE dot;


    for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++){
        for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++){
            int height = i + x;
            int width = j + y;

            if((height >= 0) && (width >= 0)){
                red += image[height][width].rgbtRed;
                blue += image[height][width].rgbtBlue;
                green += image[height][width].rgbtGreen;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    dot.rgbtRed = round(red / count);
    dot.rgbtBlue = round(blue / count);
    dot.rgbtGreen = round(green / count);

    return dot;
}
```

Comment: Are VLAs being taught in CS50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `height` or `width` objects declared at file scope.

The scope of a parameter declaration in a function prototype that is not part of a function definition ends at the end of the prototype.  This means, among other things, that

- multiple prototypes for the same function do not need to be consistent with regard to parameter names, and
- in-scope function prototypes do not provide parameter declarations for other prototypes of the same function, whether part of a function definition or not.

Consider, then, these related diagnostics:

> ```
> helpers.c:78:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'height'
> RGBTRIPLE value(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y){
>                                 ^
> helpers.c:78:41: error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
> RGBTRIPLE value(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y){
>                                         ^
> ```

What, indeed, are `height` and `width` in the scope of the definition of function `value`?  There is no declaration in scope, neither from the file scope nor from elsewhere in the function definition.  Compare to this, which apparently is accepted by the compiler:

> ```
> void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]){
> ```

Note well that `sepia()` has `height` and `width` parameters.  It is to these that the `height` and `width` in that function's appearance of `image[height][width]` refer.

Additionally, the scope of a parameter declaration in a function prototype starts immediately after the declaration.  This means that parameter declarations are not in scope earlier in the parameter list.  That effect is visible in this diagnostic:

> ```
> ./helpers.h:16:35: error: use of undeclared identifier 'width'
> void swap(RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pix, int width);
>                                   ^
> ```

Note well that although that function has a `width` parameter, it appears *after* `image` in the parameter list, therefore it is not in scope for the declaration of `image`.

If you want to use variable-length array parameters then follow the model of the functions the compiler accepts.  The parameters determining the VLA dimensions must appear earlier in the parameter list than the VLA itself.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `height` and `width` are not declared before `RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]` in these functions while they are declared in functions that don't emit errors.

You should add `height` and `width` before `image` just like other functions like this:

```
void swap(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int row, int pix){
```

```
RGBTRIPLE value(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width], int x, int y){
```

Comment: Why does it occur like that?

Comment: @narusin because you wrote it like that?